# easy way to escape html using jquery in ie 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, innerhtml

I want to convert text such as `"x < y"` into the properly-escaped `"x &lt; y"`.  I've been using the browser's built in escaping functionality to do this:

```
 div = $('<div></div>');
 div.text(my_text);
 escaped_text = div.html();
```

This works great.... until I tested in IE 8, which eats line breaks when you call .html().  Is there a similarly concise, robust way of doing this that will work in IE 8 as well?

Comment: Not sure if you are able/want to add a lib, but [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#escape) works great.

Comment: @PaulHoenecke Thanks, this will be my fallback if I can't find a better solution.  Feel free to post it as an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) has escape/unescape methods. It is a very useful library.

Comment: Underscore's escape doesn't do anything with linebreaks, but you can manually handle them like so: `escaped_text = _.escape(my_text).replace(/\n/g, '<br/>');`  -- tested this and it seems to be equivalent to my original code in modern browsers, and works properly in IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

You could exchange the html() method for the innerHTML property like so:

```
div = $('<div></div>');
div.text(my_text);
escaped_text = div[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: Just tried this in IE 8 and it looks as though innerHTML returns the same thing as html() does?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to this:

**jQuery Code:**

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.escapeHtml = function () {
        var e = document.createElement("DIV"),
            s = '';
        e.innerHTML = $(this).val();
        s = e.textContent || e.innerText || "";
        e.remove();
        return s.replace(/<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>?/gi, '');
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**How to Use:**

```
// if you want to real input value then, go with jQuery '.val()' option
var htmlString = $('#yourelement').val();

// remove html character, go with jQuery '.escapeHtml()' option
var safeHtmlString = $('#yourelement').escapeHtml();
```

or you can use as jQuery plugin:

[jQuery.escapeHtml()](https://github.com/neerajsinghsonu/jQuery.escapeHtml)